# Keep data if transaction fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions

I've got a transaction which needs detailed logging, even if it fails. How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
# csv gets loaded etc.
import = CsvImport.new
import.logger += 'Starting import'
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  import.logger += 'CSV loaded, starting import'
  csv_array.each_with_index do |row, index|
    begin
      unless importer.has_key?(row[0])
        import.logger += 'Key not found'
        raise StandardError
      end
      result = CsvImporter.import_line(row[0])
      import.logger += 'Imported line #{index} successfully' if result
    rescue
      import.logger += 'Transaction aborted!'
    end
  end
  import.logger += 'Transaction successful!'
end
```

In a failed transaction, the logger only has "Starting import" without any of the added strings inside the transaction - obviously. How can I keep that data?

Answer (score 0):

The begin-rescue block is just a wrapper to catch exceptions. In your case you need, like you said, a transaction. You can use something like this

```
YourClass.transaction do
  # do a lot of stuff
end
```

or

```
@yourmodel.transaction do 
  # do stuff !
end
```

Look at the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

A combination of transaction and rescue block are possible: Look at the docs at section "Exception handling and rolling back"

Comment: `CsvImport.transaction` and `import.transaction` did not work or rather didn't keep the data in the import.logger attribute. How am I supposed to use it? The docs didn't tell me anything new since I was using it the way it's documented.

Comment: Anyone else got an idea how to keep the log output (or any data in general) of a transaction?

Comment: @Cojones OK, now I understand. In your code you assign the logger output to a logger which is defined inside the transaction. When this fails for sure everything gets reverted and there is nothing in the output. I think you can try:
1. define a logger outside of the transaction OR
2. directly make the output into log-files instead of collection the data inside a variable and print it afterwards

Comment: I did that, see my updated question. No luck :( I wouldn't want to write it in a file and then read it again, Any other solutions to this?

Comment: What bout this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685912/how-do-i-exclude-a-model-from-a-transaction-in-activerecord